# How to add fields dynamically with adding a new product to ManyToMany field

Tags: python, sql, django, subquery

I'm trying create a Restaurant Order management system based on django

when someone order some kinds of foods , it may order 3 Pizza with 2 sandwich , how to let the customer to define the quantities of each product , and then calculate with its prices

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_names = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant, blank=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

total price of orders , for one product for example : one pizza with one sandwich however they order more than one pizza and sandwich

```
    @property
    def total(self):  
        return self.product_names.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
```

I expected to provide a quantity field for each selected items : pizza : 3 , sandwich:2 , then calculate them (3*pizza price , 2*sandwich price)

Comment: I think it's better to rename `Restaurant` to `Product`

Comment: you right , but its not the problem

Comment: It does nto seem to make much sense to define `quantity` here at the `Topping`level? Shouldn't this be encoded in the "through" field of the `Topping` to `Restaurant` model?

Comment: i have made the form with Restaurant Model ,you mean the owner of the restaurant define the quantities for each product which selected by a customer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should construct a [**`through=...`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) in the [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Sum

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductOrder')

    @property
    def total(self):  
        return self.productorder_set.aggregate(
            price_sum=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'))
        )['price_sum'] 

class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

A `ProductOrder` is thus a record in the many-to-many relation, it thus denotes that that `product` is a part of that `order` with the given `quantity`.

We can then calculate the total price with `Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'))`, so the sum of the quantity of these records times the price of the related product.

Comment: thanks alot, but how to iterate through values my context name=order_objects (template.html : {% for obj in order_objects %} {{obj.name}} : {% for i in obj.products.all %} {{ i.product }} : {{i.quantity}} ) it doesnt work !? it there something wrong !?thanks for your advice

Comment: You should iterate throug `{% for i in obj.productorder_set.all %} {{ i.product.name }}: {{ i.quantity }} {% endfor %}` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ProductQuantity` model, which will have product and quantity

```
class ProductQuantity(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

Then create an `Order` model, which will have a `ManyToManyField` reference to `ProductQuantity`

```
class Order(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
   products = models.ManyToManyField(ProductQuantity)

   @property
   def total():
       return sum([element.product.price * element.product.quantity for element in self.products.all()])
```

This way each `Order` element will have a list of products and each product will have the product and the quantity.